# Free currency rates conversion web service

Tags: web-services, web

We're going to programmatically get currency rates? Base currencies to be supported are USD and EUR. Could you please recommend some services?

I know about ECB (http://www.ecb.int/stats/eurofxref/eurofxref-daily.xml) but it supported EUR only